# libwebsockets write to all active connections after receive

Tags: libwebsockets

I am toying around with a libwebsockets tutorial trying to make it such that, after it receives a message from a connection over a given protocol, it sends a response to all active connections implementing that protocol.  I have used the function `libwebsocket_callback_all_protocol` but it is not doing what I think it should do from its name (I'm not quite sure what it does from the documentation).

The goal is to have two webpages open and, when info is sent from one, the result will be relayed to both.  Below is my code - you'll see that `libwebsocket_callback_all_protocol` is called in main (which currently does nothing, I think....) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libwebsockets.h>
#include <string.h>

static int callback_http(struct libwebsocket_context * this,
                         struct libwebsocket *wsi,
                         enum libwebsocket_callback_reasons reason, void *user,
                         void *in, size_t len)
{
    return 0;
}

static int callback_dumb_increment(struct libwebsocket_context * this,
                                   struct libwebsocket *wsi,
                                   enum libwebsocket_callback_reasons reason,
                                   void *user, void *in, size_t len)
{

    switch (reason) {
        case LWS_CALLBACK_ESTABLISHED: // just log message that someone is connecting
            printf("connection established\n");
            break;
        case LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE: { // the funny part
            // create a buffer to hold our response
            // it has to have some pre and post padding. You don't need to care
            // what comes there, libwebsockets will do everything for you. For more info see
            // http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/tree/lib/libwebsockets.h#n597
            unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*) malloc(LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + len +
                                                         LWS_SEND_BUFFER_POST_PADDING);

            int i;

            // pointer to `void *in` holds the incomming request
            // we're just going to put it in reverse order and put it in `buf` with
            // correct offset. `len` holds length of the request.
            for (i=0; i < len; i++) {
                buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING + (len - 1) - i ] = ((char *) in)[i];
            }

            // log what we recieved and what we're going to send as a response.
            // that disco syntax `%.*s` is used to print just a part of our buffer
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189071/print-part-of-char-array
            printf("received data: %s, replying: %.*s\n", (char *) in, (int) len,
                 buf + LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING);

            // send response
            // just notice that we have to tell where exactly our response starts. That's
            // why there's `buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING]` and how long it is.
            // we know that our response has the same length as request because
            // it's the same message in reverse order.
            libwebsocket_write(wsi, &buf[LWS_SEND_BUFFER_PRE_PADDING], len, LWS_WRITE_TEXT);

            // release memory back into the wild
            free(buf);
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}

static struct libwebsocket_protocols protocols[] = {
    /* first protocol must always be HTTP handler */
    {
        "http-only",   // name
        callback_http, // callback
        0,              // per_session_data_size
        0
    },
    {
        "dumb-increment-protocol", // protocol name - very important!
        callback_dumb_increment,   // callback
        0,                          // we don't use any per session data
        0

    },
    {
        NULL, NULL, 0, 0   /* End of list */
    }
};

int main(void) {
    // server url will be http://localhost:9000
    int port = 9000;
    const char *interface = NULL;
    struct libwebsocket_context *context;
    // we're not using ssl
    const char *cert_path = NULL;
    const char *key_path = NULL;
    // no special options
    int opts = 0;

    // create libwebsocket context representing this server
    struct lws_context_creation_info info;
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);   

    info.port = port;
    info.iface = interface;
    info.protocols = protocols;
    info.extensions = libwebsocket_get_internal_extensions();
    info.ssl_cert_filepath = cert_path;
    info.ssl_private_key_filepath = key_path;
    info.gid = -1;
    info.uid = -1;
    info.options = opts;
    info.user = NULL;
    info.ka_time = 0;
    info.ka_probes = 0;
    info.ka_interval = 0;

    /*context = libwebsocket_create_context(port, interface, protocols,
                                          libwebsocket_get_internal_extensions,
                                          cert_path, key_path, -1, -1, opts);
   */
    context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
    if (context == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "libwebsocket init failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    libwebsocket_callback_all_protocol(&protocols[1], LWS_CALLBACK_RECEIVE);

    printf("starting server...\n");

    // infinite loop, to end this server send SIGTERM. (CTRL+C)
    while (1) {
        libwebsocket_service(context, 50);
        // libwebsocket_service will process all waiting events with their
        // callback functions and then wait 50 ms.
        // (this is a single threaded webserver and this will keep our server
        // from generating load while there are not requests to process)
    }

    libwebsocket_context_destroy(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the `libwebsocket_write` on `LWS_CALLBACK_ESTABLISHED` generate some random segfault so using the mail list the libwebsockets developer Andy Green instructed me the correct way is to use `libwebsocket_callback_on_writable_all_protocol`, the file `test-server/test-server.c` in library source code shows sample of use.

```
libwebsocket_callback_on_writable_all_protocol(libwebsockets_get_protocol(wsi))
```

It worked very well to notify all instances, but it only call the write method in all connected instances, it do not define the data to send. You need to manage the data yourself. The sample source file `test-server.c` show a sample ring buffer to do it.

http://ml.libwebsockets.org/pipermail/libwebsockets/2015-January/001580.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Did you manage to write code that sends data to all instances?

Comment: Yes, works like a charm... as said, look at `test-server.c` in libwebsocket git source code, to see a working code.
http://git.libwebsockets.org/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/tree/test-server/test-server.c

Answer (score 0):

From what I can quickly grab from the documentation, in order to send a message to all clients, what you should do is store somewhere (in a vector, a hashmap, an array, whatever) the `struct libwebsocket * wsi` that you have access when your clients connect.

Then when you receive a message and want to broadcast it, simply call `libwebsocket_write` on all `wsi *` instances.

That's what I'd do, anyway.